# Menu closes when clicking outside it but only opens once

Tags: jquery

I've created a collapsible menu and I want it to be closed when user clicks on body. I've coded it but it just work for once in every refresh. I mean it opens when I click menu button and nicely closed when I click on body but if I want to reopen the menu, button doesn't do anything.

I tried `addclass` instead of `toggleclass` but it doesn't work. even i tried `toggleClass` instead of `removeClass` but something worse had happened, every time I click on BODY, menu is going to open and close.

What's going wrong?

```js
$(window).click(function() {
  "use strict";
  $("HTML, body").click(function() {
    $(".menu").removeClass("menu_slide");
  });
});

$(document).ready(function() {
  "use strict";
  $(".menu_button").click(function() {
    $(".menu").toggleClass("menu_slide");
  });
});
```

```css
.menu_button {
  position: fixed;
  cursor: pointer;
  color: #727272;
  /*margin-top: -10vw;*/
  margin-left: 3vw;
  margin-top: 3vw;
  text-shadow: 2px 1.5px 2px #0C0C0C;
  z-index: 200;
}

.slash {
  font-family: 'Montserrat-Medium';
  font-size: 4vw;
  letter-spacing: 0.5vw;
  text-shadow: 2px 1.5px 2px #0C0C0C;
  z-index: 200;
  -webkit-transition: 0.3s ease-out;
  -moz-transition: 0.3s ease-out;
  -o-transition: 0.3s ease-out;
  transition: 0.3s ease-out;
}

.menu {
  width: 50vw;
  height: 100vh;
  background-color: #D1D1D1;
  z-index: 10;
  position: fixed;
  left: -50vw;
  top: 0vh;
  -moz-transition: 0.8s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: 0.8s ease-in-out;
  -webkit-transition: 0.8s ease-in-out;
  transition: 0.8s ease-in-out;
}

.menu_slide {
  left: 0vw;
  -moz-transition: 0.8s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: 0.8s ease-in-out;
  -webkit-transition: 0.8s ease-in-out;
  transition: 0.8s ease-in-out;
}

.menu ul {
  position: absolute;
  left: 20vw;
  top: 18vw;
}

.menu ul li {
  font-family: 'Montserrat-Light';
  font-size: 1.5vw;
  line-height: 2vw;
  letter-spacing: 0.3vw;
  color: #1C1C1C;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="menu_button">
  <div class="slash">///</div>
</div>
<div class="menu">
  <ul>
    <li>About /</li>
    <li>CV /</li>
    <li>Photos /</li>
    <li>Videos /</li>
    <li>Contact /</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

The issue is because the clicks on the `.menu` element are propagating up to the `body` where the class you just added gets immediately removed. Your nested event handler within `window.click` is doing a similar job, which is why nested event handler should generally be avoided.

To fix this you need to add a `stopPropagation()` call to a parent element of the menu. You should also only attach the first click handler, which hides the menu, directly on the `document`. Try this:

```js
$(document).click(function() {
  $(".menu").removeClass("menu_slide");
});

$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".menu_button").click(function() {
    $(".menu").toggleClass("menu_slide");
  });
  
  $('.menu-container').on('click', function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
  });
});
```

```css
.menu_button {
  position: fixed;
  cursor: pointer;
  color: #727272;
  /*margin-top: -10vw;*/
  margin-left: 3vw;
  margin-top: 3vw;
  text-shadow: 2px 1.5px 2px #0C0C0C;
  z-index: 200;
}

.slash {
  font-family: 'Montserrat-Medium';
  font-size: 4vw;
  letter-spacing: 0.5vw;
  text-shadow: 2px 1.5px 2px #0C0C0C;
  z-index: 200;
  -webkit-transition: 0.3s ease-out;
  -moz-transition: 0.3s ease-out;
  -o-transition: 0.3s ease-out;
  transition: 0.3s ease-out;
}

.menu {
  width: 50vw;
  height: 100vh;
  background-color: #D1D1D1;
  z-index: 10;
  position: fixed;
  left: -50vw;
  top: 0vh;
  -moz-transition: 0.8s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: 0.8s ease-in-out;
  -webkit-transition: 0.8s ease-in-out;
  transition: 0.8s ease-in-out;
}

.menu_slide {
  left: 0vw;
  -moz-transition: 0.8s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: 0.8s ease-in-out;
  -webkit-transition: 0.8s ease-in-out;
  transition: 0.8s ease-in-out;
}

.menu ul {
  position: absolute;
  left: 20vw;
  top: 18vw;
}

.menu ul li {
  font-family: 'Montserrat-Light';
  font-size: 1.5vw;
  line-height: 2vw;
  letter-spacing: 0.3vw;
  color: #1C1C1C;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="menu-container">
  <div class="menu_button">
    <div class="slash">///</div>
  </div>
  <div class="menu">
    <ul>
      <li>About /</li>
      <li>CV /</li>
      <li>Photos /</li>
      <li>Videos /</li>
      <li>Contact /</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: My god, Thanks you are amazing. believe it or not i was stuck here for a whole week.